# How to access PHP Associative Array with unkonwn Associative names

Tags: php, arrays, associative

My PHP Array (example, Print_r dump)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Nick] => Bobby
            [FullName] => Bob Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Nick] => Mikey
            [FullName] => Mike Smithers
        )

)
```

If I don't know the values "Nick" or "FullName" how can I access the values in them.

The array will have two values and I was looking to understand how to get access to them if I don't know the name of it.

I would like it to print out (for example)

Output example trying to get to:
"Value one is Bobbie value two is Bob Smith "

but I don't know [Nick] or [FullName] how would one access "Bobbie" or "Bob Smith" (Array being passed in)

Thanks.

Comment: `foreach` loop should do what you need.

Comment: Bigger picture question: If you don't know what you're looking for, how will you know you've found it?

Comment: Bigger picture is that I am working on a function that can handle stuff in and be able to still process it..  So that is why it is unknown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($list as $array) { 
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "The value of {$key} is: {$value}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach ($my_arr as $key => $value) {
    list( $value_one, $value_two) = $value;
    echo "Value one is $value_one value two is $value_two\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes but how would you get the value "Nick" to it self?

Comment: @user1283754 I updated the answer with a more accurate example.

Comment: Note Arrays in a Array from top.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the values, you can do:

```
$values = array_values($my_arr);

$values[0]; // the first value
$values[1]; // the second value
```

Comment: +1 good point -- if he doesn't know and doesn't care what the keys are, the values should do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

here are two examples for handle ....

```
 <?php 
     $array = array(array("Bobbie"=>"Bobb",
                          "BobS"=>"BobbS"),
                    array("Foo"=>"Bar",
                          "Hello"=>"World")
              );

        // Method No.1
        foreach($array as $arr) {
           foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
             echo $key."\n";
           }
        }
        // Method No.2
        // you can use the function array_keys() to get the key-names
        foreach($array as $arr) {

        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        echo "<h1>Keys:</h1><pre>".print_r($keys,1)."</pre>";
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Very useful information the array_keys function really is a good one. Thank you for sharing it..   That is/was part of the problem understanding and access elements when you don't know what is in it..  Thank you. Good stuff.